# using foo::bar doesn't mask a typedef-name ::bar?

Tags: c++, namespaces

This fragment does not compile:

```
// application code
namespace google_breakpad {
  class ExceptionHandler {
    ExceptionHandler(const char *, int);
  };
}
extern void bar(google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler *);

// from an unavoidably included system header
typedef int (*ExceptionHandler)(void *);

// more application code...
using google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler;
void foo(const char *s)
{
  bar(new ExceptionHandler(s, 0));
}
```

As the names may suggest, this is cut down from a real program.  My expectation was that regardless of what system headers might have dumped into the global namespace, the `using google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler` would suppress any *other* type named `ExceptionHandler` and make the use of bare `ExceptionHandler` inside `foo` unambiguously a reference to the class in `namespace google_breakpad`.

However, g++ and clang++ agree that this is invalid, insisting on interpreting the bare `ExceptionHandler` as a reference to the typedef-name in the global namespace.

```
$ clang++ -fsyntax-only -std=c++11 test.cc
test.cc:14:11: error: excess elements in scalar initializer
  bar(new ExceptionHandler(s, 0));
          ^                 ~~~

$ g++ -fsyntax-only -std=c++11 test.cc
test.cc: In function ‘void foo(const char*)’:
test.cc:14:32: error: new initializer expression list treated as compound expression [-fpermissive]
   bar(new ExceptionHandler(s, 0));
                                ^
test.cc:14:32: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘ExceptionHandler {aka int (*)(void*)}’ [-fpermissive]
test.cc:14:33: error: cannot convert ‘int (**)(void*)’ to ‘google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void bar(google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler*)’
   bar(new ExceptionHandler(s, 0));
                                 ^
```

(`-std=c++11` does not actually affect either compiler's behavior, but that is how the original program was being compiled.)

Q1: Are the compilers behaving correctly?

Q2: Assuming they are, is there any way to suppress the unwanted typedef-name and so make this program valid?  (Without changing any of the names.  I know I can replace the `using` with `typedef google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler BreakpadEH` and then change all subsequent uses of the bare name, but that just moves the problem around---how do I know *that* name is not polluted by system headers?  (The real translation unit winds up including order of 500 system headers, nearly all of which are OS-specific and written by people who don't appear to have cared at all about namespace pollution.))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you shouldn't be allowed to declare a new type with the same name as another already declared in the same scope, but I guess maybe this isn't true for classes versus typedefs since you can technically instruct the compiler on how to distinguish them. If you had another typedef and tried using the `using` keyword, for example, it would complain about it already being declared. The use of the using keyword on types like that doesn't override the old type, but rather is like adding a declaration to the current scope so the compiler doesn't have to search far for it. You still can't re-declare the same type though, so you can't expect this to work:

```
typedef int A
typedef char A;
```

or this

```
namespace X {
  typedef int A;
}
typedef char A;
using X::A;
```

Redeclaring a class like that seems to be some oddity, because this does not work:

```
typedef int A;
class A;
```

but this works fine

```
typedef int A;
namespace X {
  class A;
}
using X::A;
```

Of course that's where your error comes in. You've technically redeclared the type, which really shouldn't happen but it seems to quasi-work with some hacks.

In any case, you have a few options, none of which are probably exactly what you want. You can force the compiler to look for the "class" option:

```
bar(new class ExceptionHandler(s, 0));
```

Or, you can use the using statement in the function since ExceptionHandler wasn't declared in that scope yet:

```
void foo(const char *s)
{
  using google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler;
  bar(new ExceptionHandler(s, 0));
}
```

Or you can put foo in the namespace and call it out:

```
namespace google_breakpad {
  void foo(const char *s)
  {
    bar(new ExceptionHandler(s, 0));
  }
}
using google_breakpad::foo;
```

Or you can just use the namespace identifier:

```
bar(new google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler(s, 0));
```

But you can't re-declare the same type in the same scope and expect to get away with it cleanly. At least that is my understanding of it. YMMV. :-)